# Why does <pre> output differently when used in a one-line concatenated echo?

Tags: php, html, pre

A small thing, but irritating. Why does this:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($array)."</pre>";
```

...output this:

```
Array ( [0] => SP2 [1] => SP1 [2] => ennis123 )
```

Whereas, this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_of_refs_for_rm);
echo "</pre>";
```

...outputs that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SP2
    [1] => SP1
    [2] => ennis123
)
```

I'd simply like to save some vertical space in my code when debugging.

Comment: Btw, do NOT concat strings in echo. Just use a comma. Then the string must not be concatenated before the the output.

Comment: Press F12 and check the source code. You'll notice something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`print_r()`](https://php.net/print_r) writes in the output.

You can use the second parameter to redirect the output in the variable.

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($array, true)."</pre>";
```

In your case, the output was made **before** the `<pre>` tag.

Note that the function `var_export()` has the same behavior.